# No provisioning profile option under build settings

Tags: xcode6, provisioning-profile

I am using Xcode 6.3.1 and surprisingly two of the projects i created with it does not have any provisioning profile option under the build settings. All the other projects i created have this option. The deployment target is also ios 8.3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the toggle from "Basic" to "All" in the bar to the left of the search input box.  I'm not sure how you are getting the view that you have, but If you change it to "All", you should see every option and hopefully it will show up.